I want to add images in assets to powerBI Customvisual
I am creating a customvisual and integrating it with powerBI. I am using a library to use custom components , this library has its own images and fonts and so on so forth. I create a build of the angular component and use it  in customvisual. After rendering the images are not appearing, in a way it does not maps the local images in that manner pibiviz json.
Is there any solution out there sop that we can include images in powerbi, from the component whose build we are using.
I tried using webpack to bundle my images in assets and show it up there, didn;t work.
Refering to the images in css does work but i don't want to use that way, also no external hosting of images
